# Object attribute's sharing same instance

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with one of my classes.

```
public class Sequence {

    private ArrayList<Spell> spells;

    public Sequence(ArrayList<Spell> spellsEnCours) {
    this.spellsEnCours = spellsEnCours;
    ...
    }

    public Sequence(Sequence pSequence) {
    this.spells = pSequence.spells;
    ... 
    }
}
```

There is no static field nowhere in my code.

My main treatment (for example) :

```
... 
ArrayList<Spell> mySpells = new ArrayList<Spell>();
    Spell spell1 = new Spell(150, 0, 0, "Spell 1", null);
    Spell spell2 = new Spell(200, 2, 0, "Spell 2", new Buff(TypeBuff.ALLY_ATK, 2));
    Spell spell3 = new Spell(500, 3, 0, "Spell 3", null);
    mySpells.add(spell1);
    mySpells.add(spell2);
    mySpells.add(spell3);
    ArrayList<Sequence> mySequences = new ArrayList<Sequence>();
    Sequence initialSequence = new Sequence(mySpells);
    Sequence secondSequence = new Sequence(initialSequence);
    mySequences.add(initialSequence);
    // Let's just consider this call set a Spell's class attribute to true / false in the list Attribute of Spell
    secondSequence.choisirSpell(spell3);
    mySequences.add(secondSequence);
```

And the state of spells attribute in my initialSequence will be the same as in my secondSequence after the call of my method choisirSpell. It's like it's the same instance, either the HashCode is different.

And i what i want is that the spells attribute for those two object are not related in anyway, independent.

Comment: The reason is that the both use the same reference to the List `mySpells`. A solution would be to to initialize the second Sequence with an empty List and then call: `secondSequence.spells.addAll(mySpells)`.
EDIT: now that I have a closer look at it you could simply replace the second constructor to: `this.spells = new ArrayList<>(); this.spells.addAll(pSequence.spells);`

Comment: `this.spells = pSequence.spells;` results that `spells` is the same instance as `pSequence.spells`. Create a new instance like  `this.spells = new ArrayList<>(pSequence.spells);`

Answer (score 1):

First thing, in your constructor for Sequence that accepts another sequence, you are just assigning the same spells list to your new sequence. Instead use:

```
this.spells = new ArrayList<>(pSequence.spells);
```

Second, even if you do like above, only the list objects are different but still both lists have same Spell objects. So setting a property of spell will be reflecting on both lists.

To avoid that you must create a new spell object with same spell attributes if you intend the second list to ave completely its own new copy of spell. You may create a Copy constructor or clone method on Spell to do this.

This way, though the Spell objects are added from first list to second, it will still be a separate entity.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks you for your clear answer ! :)